# How to place readable text on image, without manipulating the text?

Tags: text, images

I want to place some text on images, without adding effects to the text itself. Which one should I change on the image (hue, saturation, brightness) and in which direction so the text will be readable?

The text can be either white, or black(I will go with one of these two, depending on the solution that arises), and the images can be bright or dark images also.

Is this possible by only manipulating the three properties of the image?

Comment: Hi Adam, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Is this for print or screen?

Comment: This is for screen:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, you can manipulate an image using brightness alone to have overlaid text legible.

If your text is white, you'll want to lower the brightness and if it is black, increase the brightness.

Saturation will increase/decrease the amount of color in the image and hue will change the overall make-up of color in the image. So you may want to change these depending on what you visually are going for.

All this being said, depending on things like text size, the image itself, font, etc. this may be ill-advised. In most cases you will need to really brighten or darken an image to make it work and it might not end up looking good. But, you as the designer will be the judge of that!

Comment: Hi hkaube, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!